# GParted will not start, corrupt GPT table

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, gpt

I'm trying to start GParted and get the following series of errors in pop-up boxes before it eventually quits:

```
Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sda

Libparted Bug Found! The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary
appears OK, so that will be used.

Libparted Bug Found! Assertion (last_usable <= disk->dev->length) at
../../../libparted/labels/gpt.c:994 in function _parse_header()
failed.
```

Ubuntu 14.04 running as the sole operating system on an Asus Zenbook.

Thanks!

sgdisk -v output:

```
Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v'
to verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to
repair the disk. Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main
header; regenerating backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

 ****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT,
but disk verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table
may be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup
partition table when you save your partitions.

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't
reside at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array,
use the 'e' option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary
header's and partition table's locations.

Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data! (Disk size is
250069680 sectors, needs to be 457179648 sectors.) The 'e' option on
the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last
usable sector is 457179614, but backup header is at 457179647 and disk
size is 250069680 sectors. The 'e' option on the experts' menu will
probably fix this problem

Problem: partition 7 is too big for the disk.

Problem: partition 8 is too big for the disk.

Identified 6 problems!
```

Comment: You might try booting from media containing the latest [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) which includes newer versions of gparted and the underlying partition library libparted.

Comment: Please type `sudo sgdisk -v /dev/sda` and post the output. (Edit your original question, and add four spaces to the start of each line to keep it legible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sgdisk -v` error output summarizes the problem. Basically, the disk is roughly half the size that the GPT data structures claim it is -- the disk's actual size (as determined by the Linux kernel) is 250,069,680 sectors (119 GiB), but the GPT claims that the disk is 457,179,647 sectors (218 GiB).

This problem might occur if:

- You pulled a single disk out of a RAID array and tried to use it individually.
- You're using motherboard-based software RAID (popularly, but somewhat inaccurately, called "fake RAID") but either:

  - You haven't activated the appropriate drivers in Ubuntu
  - You access the `/dev/sd?` devices rather than device files in `/dev/mapper/`; the latter is required when accessing this type of RAID.
- You've accidentally set the [Host Protected Area (HPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) feature on the disk. You can check this by typing `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda` (or similarly for other disks). If the results indicate that HPA is active, you can reset it by adjusting the number of visible sectors with the same command, but passing the number of sectors to the `-N` parameter. (Type `man hdparm` and search for "protected" to find the entry on this feature.)
- Your disk hardware has gone south and is reporting the wrong values. This is most often the case with USB flash drives.

You haven't given enough context to know which of these explanations is most likely. There may also be other possible causes that I've forgotten or that I simply don't know about.

Comment: Some Zenbooks use RAID and drive is confused if size is one drive or two drives or your fakeRAID issue.

Comment: Thanks Rod, Oldfred. This particular Zenbook does have a 2x128Gb SSD, which I didn't totally understand the significance of when I bought it, or when I installed Ubuntu. HPA is disabled. Do you think this means I've installed everything to 1 of 2 disks?

Comment: See the [Fake RAID HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) for information on how to use that technology. Depending on your needs (dual boot, etc.) you might want to completely deactivate it and use the two disks separately or activate it fully and use the two disks as if they were one. Personally, I'd avoid this type of RAID on an Ubuntu-only installation.

Comment: @Rod, Do you think I should start from scratch and reinstall?

Comment: Re-installing without addressing the underlying cause of the problem will solve nothing. Once you identify and fix the underlying cause, a re-install may become unnecessary. If you're certain you're not using HPA and you have multiple disks, then chances are you've got a RAID issue. There are lots and lots of questions and answers here about RAID; or check the [Ubuntu Fake RAID HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) for some background information.